# DB2 SQL instead of update trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

Hi I have the following code, for create a DB2 SQL trigger, extended

```
connect to sample
@

drop TABLE countries
@
drop view view1
@
drop TRIGGER update_view1_2
@

CREATE TABLE countries (id int, country varchar(50), region varchar (50), average_temp int)
@
CREATE VIEW view1 (id, continent, temperature) as SELECT id, region, average_temp from countries
@

CREATE TRIGGER update_view1_2
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON view1
REFERENCING OLD AS o NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW
MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    UPDATE countries c
    SET c.region = n.continent
    WHERE c.region = o.continent;
END
@
```

I run this script with this:
`db2 -td@ -v -f trig_ipd_wiev1.db2 -z procs.log`

----PROBLEM SOLVED----

Comment: What is the error code?

Comment: DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned: SQL0206N  "N.REGION" is not valid in the context where it is used.  LINE NUMBER=7.  SQLSTATE=42703

Comment: Is it a trigger on a view? or in a table?

Comment: Does the view `view1` actually contain the column `region`? Show us the table and the view definitions by adding them to the question.

Comment: @AngocA Yes, it's an "instead of" trigger, what is defined on view

Comment: I found the solution

Comment: Please share it with us as an "answer"

Comment: The n.region was a column in the table, not in the view, so the solution is:
`SET c.region = n.continent
WHERE c.region = o.continent;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that, there was

`SET c.region = n.region
WHERE c.region = o.region;`

instead of

`SET c.region = n.continent
WHERE c.region = o.continent;`